# How to check value is null or blank in sails js

Tags: mysql, sails.js, waterline

How can I check value is null or blank in sails using waterline. I can do this with mysql native query but due to some reason I don't want to use it.

I have tried something like below code but it's not working.

```
var query = {
    Status: [1, 2, 3],
    Date: [null, '']
};
table.count(query).exec(function (err, count) {
    if (err) {
        return res.badRequest(err);
    }
    return res.send(count);
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use [or query](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/query-language#?or-pairs)

```
var query = {
    Status : [1, 2, 3],
    or     : [
      { Date : null },
      { Date : '' },
    ],
};
```